# JQuery - Multiple show / hide div with external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/s2CtY/16/ which works perfectly.  However what l need is for

1.The click to show the DIV plus open an external link
2. To allow multiples of this via PHP

Can anyone help ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sub-nav ul').css("display","none");
    // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
    $('.sub-nav-btn').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
    $('.sub-nav').on('click', 'ul', function () {
        $(this).prev(".sub-nav-btn").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).slideToggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn"><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">btn1</a></div>
  <ul>btn1 slide data
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-nav">
 <div class="sub-nav-btn">btn2</div>
  <ul>btn2 data slide
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want load some partial view or open whole separate website in iframe?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific when saying "plus open an external link". In a new tab? An iframe?

Comment: In a new window please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using `window.open();`
Capture the links URL into a var and pass that var to `window.open()` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sub-nav ul').css("display","none");
        // Watch for clicks on the "slide" link.
        $('.sub-nav-btn').click(function () {
            var url = $(this).children('a').attr('href');
            if(url != null){
                window.open(url);
            }
            $(this).next(".sub-nav ul").slideToggle(400);
            $(this).slideToggle(400);
            return false;
        });
        $('.sub-nav').on('click', 'ul', function () {
            $(this).prev(".sub-nav-btn").slideToggle(400);
            $(this).slideToggle(400);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/s2CtY/29/)
Hope this helps!